# Can’t insert into one table in particular

Tags: php, mysql

I’m trying to insert data into a certain table, which doesn’t work. Using the same code to insert into other tables work:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO projects (name, desc) VALUES ('$name', '$desc')";

if($this->conn->query($sql) !== true)
{
    echo(mysqli_error($this->model->conn));
}
```

When using it on the table I wish to insert data into (`projects`), it informs me with the following:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc) VALUES ('das', 'das')' at line...

---

On the other hand, using the same code--modifying it a slight bit:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (forename, surname) VALUES ('$name', '$desc')";
```

This successfully inserts `$name` and `$desc` into the `users` table.

Both `forename` and `surname` in the `users` table, have the same types as `name` and `desc` in the `projects` table. The database is connected to in the “usual” way, using the object oriented version of *PHP*’s *MySQL*.

---

It would appear to me as though I’m not doing anything wrong. Perhaps someone has experienced something similar at some point and thus can point me in the right direction?

Comment: at a time you are trying to insert the data in both tables?

Comment: @D.Ataro Mention your projects table structure

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue here is your table name desc, which is a reserved MySQL keyword.
See:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Wrapping it in back ticks may work:

```
(name, `desc`)
```

[When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

But I would recommend changing your table name.

Comment: That works brilliantly! It’s a darn good thing clients don’t get to know about your utter failures!

Comment: Yeah, MySQL is strange that way. Every other platform is different.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'projects' ('name', 'desc') VALUES ('$name', '$desc');";
```

This would ensure all reserved keywords are interpreted correctly, not that I see any particular keyword.